# UWP Bluetooth RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync is null

Tags: bluetooth, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm trying to connect to an device with UWP using following code:

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromConnectionStatus(BluetoothConnectionStatus.Disconnected));
var device = devices.FirstOrDefault()
if (device != null && device.Name == "MyDevice")
{
    var rfcommService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
    var socket = new StreamSocket();
    await _socket.ConnectAsync(rfDeviceService.ConnectionHostName, rfDeviceService.ConnectionServiceName);
}
```

I manage to find my device, with all information.

RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(device.Id) always returns null, and since it returns null so fast it feels like it event cant "connect" or receive the information.

My Package ApplicationManifest has following entites related to this:

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

Anyone succesfull manage to connect to an Bluetooth device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been looking for answer since yesterday, and 10m after I post I found an example with the answer. I just post it here so other people will find in the future:

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromConnectionStatus(BluetoothConnectionStatus.Disconnected));
var device = devices.FirstOrDefault()
if (device != null && device.Name == "MyDevice")
{
    var bluetoothDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
    var rfcommServices = await bluetoothDevice.GetRfcommServicesForIdAsync(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort.Uuid), BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
    if (rfcommServices.Services.Count > 0)
    {
        var service = rfcommServices.Services[0];
        await _socket.ConnectAsync(service.ConnectionHostName, service.ConnectionServiceName);
    }
}
```

Could definetly write to code more beautiful, just showing how you can get it to work :)

Comment: I still get null from BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id).. Trying to get my JBL headphones' battery level..

Comment: Actually the answer from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2ed8563-0a3a-4479-b529-82a4ab2db8f2/why-does-rfcommdeviceservicefromidasync-return-null?forum=winappswithcsharp) fixed the issue. Needed to add bluetooth capability to Package.appxmanifest

Comment: @pantonis 
Unfortunately don't I have access to that code anymore